# Dismissing the keyboard while simulating a wait

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, resignfirstresponder

This function is designed to simulate a wait if the user is successful logging in. As you can see I dismiss the keyboard first but that doesn't stop NSThread from sleeping before the keyboard is dismissed. I think I need to harness the power of the dispatch queue but not quite sure. Any way I can dismiss the keyboard before sleep occurs?

```
-(IBAction)userLoginButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    /* resign first responders so that the user
     can see the label of the server trying to log in */
    [self.usernameField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Logging In...";

    // create the server object and pass in the username and password values
    IONServer *server = [[IONServer alloc] init];
    NSString *user = self.usernameField.text;
    NSString *pw = self.passwordField.text;
    [server loggingInWithUserName:user password:pw];

    // redirect based on result
    if (server.result.success) {
        [self serverSuccess];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
    } else {
        [self serverFailure];
    }

    // store the server object as this class' server var
    self.server = server;
    NSLog(@"Result From Server: %@", server.result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dismissing the keyboard is animated and this is enough for us to know that it happens async-ly, on main thread. In other words - you code block starts, dismissing the keyboard being added to main thread runloop, the thread sleeps for 2 seconds because you said so (Terrible thing to do if you ask me), and only than it's the keyboard's turn to get animated down and be dismissed.

A nice trick can be

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations: ^{
    [self.usernameField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordField resignFirstResponder];
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    // Do whatever needed...
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
}];
```

BUT - I highly recommend finding a better solution than freezing the main thread.

Also - no what you asked for, but, assuming all your text fields are subviews of `self.view` you can just call `[self.view endEditing:YES];` and you don't need to care about which text field is corrently the responder.

Comment: I'll accept the answer (with added tip) but you may want to update the block to     [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view endEditing:YES];
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
    }];

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer, I wrote the code out of my head and assumed some typos...